# mkvmerge linux command Backward Spliting not supported

Tags: linux, mkv

I tried this:-

`mkvmerge -o new_file.ogg --split parts:0s-104s,+94s-208s,+8s-12s,+312s-410s,+17s-21s 500.ogg`

Thrown this error:

`"The start time must be bigger than or equal to the previous part's end time"`

because 94 I see in code backward spliting point not allowed.

```
if (!requested_split_points.empty() && (start(requested_split_points.back()))) {
    if (frames_fields)
      throw format_x{boost::format(Y("Invalid start frame/field number for '--split' in '--split %1%' (current part: %2%). The start number must be bigger than or equal to the previous part's end number.\n")) % arg % part_spec};
   else
      throw format_x{boost::format(Y("Invalid start time for '--split' in '--split %1%' (current part: %2%). The start time must be bigger than or equal to the previous part's end time.\n")) % arg % part_spec};
}
```

Can you please guide how to split randomly in entire stream. I want to split some portion backward , some upward, anywhere random between stream anytime..

Does it possible?

Comment: just have a look at the manual: https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge.html#mkvmerge.description.split

Comment: I saw earlier that but can't but should that work can't display details about these

Comment: if backward splitting not support then you can first cut into pieces from original & then join with backward & upward portion one by one. You can try with FFmpeg tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have a look at the manual: https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge.html#mkvmerge.description.split

I saw but can't work it. Not displaying details about these.

So, if backward splitting not support then you can first cut into pieces from original & then join with backward & upward portion one by one.